# OpenGL ES 2.0 glDrawElements odd behavior

Tags: c, opengl-es-2.0

In my application (running on Mali-400 GPU) I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 to draw UI. For that I setup orthogonal projection matrix and use 2D vectors to describe the geometry (only x, y attributes).

So my vertex structure looks something like this:

```
struct my_vertext {
    struct vec2 pos;
    struct unsigned int color;
}
```

later then I prepare GL context, setup shaders:

vertex:

```
uniform mat4 matrix;
attribute vec2 pos;
attribute vec4 color;
varying vec4 frag_color;
void main() {
   frag_color = color;
   gl_Position = matrix * vec4(pos.xy, 0, 1);
};
```

fragment:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 frag_color;
void main() {
   gl_FragColor = frag_color;
};
```

and bind them with attribute arrays:

```
GLuint prog = glCreateProgram(); CHECK_GL;
// create shaders, load source and compile them
...
/// binding with attributes
GLuint attrib_pos, attrib_col, vertex_index = 0;
glBindAttribLocation(prog, vertex_index, "pos"); CHECK_GL;
attrib_pos = vertex_index++;
glBindAttribLocation(prog, vertex_index, "color"); CHECK_GL;
attrib_col = vertex_index++;

// link program
glLinkProgram(prog); CHECK_GL;

glUseProgram(prog); CHECK_GL;
```

When I render my geometry (for simplicity I am drawing 2 rectangles one behind another) - only the first call to **glDrawElements** produces an image on the screen (dark gray rectangle), the second (red) - doesn`t.
For rendering I am using Vertex Array Object with 2 bound buffers - one for geometry (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER) and the second one for indices (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER). All the geometry is placed to this buffers and later is drawn with **glDrawElements** calls providing needed offsets.

My drawing code:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao); CHECK_GL;

...
GLuint *offset = 0;
for each UI object:
{
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)ui_object->elem_count,
        GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, offset); CHECK_GL;
    offset += ui_object->elem_count;
}
```

This puzzles me a lot since **I check each and every return code of glXXX functions** and all of them return **GL_NO_ERROR**. Additionally, I ran my program in Mali Graphics Debugger and the latter hasn`t revealed any problems/errors.

Geometry and indices for both calls (obtained from Mali Graphics Debugger):

```
First rectangle geometry (which is shown on screen):
0 Position=[30.5, 30.5]     Color=[45, 45, 45, 255]
1 Position=[1250.5, 30.5]   Color=[45, 45, 45, 255]
2 Position=[1250.5, 690.5]  Color=[45, 45, 45, 255]
3 Position=[30.5, 690.5]    Color=[45, 45, 45, 255]

Indices: [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]

Second rectangle geometry (which isnt` shown on screen):
4 Position=[130.5, 130.5]   Color=[255, 0, 0, 255]
5 Position=[230.5, 130.5]   Color=[255, 0, 0, 255]
6 Position=[230.5, 230.5]   Color=[255, 0, 0, 255]
7 Position=[130.5, 230.5]   Color=[255, 0, 0, 255]

Indices: [4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7]
```

P.S.: On my desktop everything works perfectly. I suppose it has something to do with limitations/peculiarities of embedded Open GL.

```
On my desktop:
$ inxi -F
$ ....
$ GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Desktop GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
```

Comment: One thing that looks like a problem is that you use `elem_count` to calculate the offset passed to `glDrawElements()`, while that offset must be in bytes. Also, do you have the depth test enabled? If you do, the second rectangle might simply be eliminated by the depth test, since it's coplanar with the first one.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Thank you for your hints, but **offset** is a pointer to **unsigned short** which means it increments in bytes and depth test is disabled `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` before actual rendering.

Comment: It's declared as type `GLuint` in the code you posted.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Sorry, it was a pointer to GLuint. I`ve corrected the post.

Comment: Are you able to make complete minimal code that fails?

Comment: That would still be wrong, a pointer to `GLuint` addresses 4-byte values, while you're passing `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` for the index type, which is 2 bytes per index.

Answer (score 0):

I know very little of OpenGL ES, but this part looks wrong:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao); CHECK_GL;

...
GLuint *offset = 0;
for each UI object:
{
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)ui_object->elem_count,
        GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, offset); CHECK_GL;
    offset += ui_object->elem_count;
}
```

compared to

```
glBindVertexArray(vao); CHECK_GL;

...
GLuint offset = 0;
for each UI object:
{
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)ui_object->elem_count,
        GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &offset); CHECK_GL;
    offset += ui_object->elem_count;
}
```

Comment: Further search on the last parameter to glDrawElements: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html reveals that the last parameter should contain input data. Your code is somewhat incomplete in order to test

Comment: This is ok, since I`m binding a Vertex Array Object (vao) before actual render loop. All the data are coming from it. As to the pointer in the last argument - it is treated only as a offset inside bound buffer object, not as an actual pointer to a live data.